# spark kafka producer serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kafka-producer-api

I come up with the exception:

> ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2032)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:889)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:888)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:888)   at
>   com.Boot$.test(Boot.scala:60)     at com.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:36)    at
>   com.Boot.main(Boot.scala)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:525)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer, value:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@77624599)
>     - field (class: com.Boot$$anonfun$test$1, name: producer$1, type: class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
>     - object (class com.Boot$$anonfun$test$1, )  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)

```
//    @transient
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()

sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

//    @transient
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val requestSet: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(s"hdfs:/user/bigdata/ADVERTISE-IMPRESSION-STAT*/*")

//    @transient
val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, NearLineConfig.kafka_brokers)
//    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
//    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("producer.type", "async")
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "49152")

//    @transient
val producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

requestSet.foreachPartition((partisions: Iterator[String]) => {
  partisions.foreach((line: String) => {
    try {
      producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("testtopic", line))
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => {
        log.warn(ex.getMessage, ex)
      }
    }
  })
})

producer.close()
```

In this program i try to read the records from the hdfs path and save them into kafka. 
  the problem is when I remove the codes about sending records to kafka , it runs well. 
  What I missed ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`KafkaProducer` isn't serializable. You'll need to move the creation of the instance to inside `foreachPartition`:

```
requestSet.foreachPartition((partitions: Iterator[String]) => {
  val producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  partitions.foreach((line: String) => {
    try {
      producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("testtopic", line))
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => {
        log.warn(ex.getMessage, ex)
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Note that `KafkaProducer.send` returns a `Future[RecordMetadata]`, and the only exception that can propagate from it is `SerializationException` if the key or value can't be serialized.

Comment: thank you very much . I did your way to change my code . it works .

Comment: @Steven.Prgm What did he mention?

Comment: By the way , one of my workmate mentioned the driver variable and the executor variable, is it any difference between them ?

Comment: @Steven.Prgm The first way you created it, the driver had to serialize the `KafkaProducer` to the worker. The way I proposed, the `KafkaProducer` is created once for each partition of the data, and the code runs inside the executor on each worker node.

Comment: so, it is more like the driver is not able to serialize the KafkaProducer object and transmit to the worker. but if KafkaProducer is created by the executor, it donot need to consider the serialization and transmission. (if i think this way is ok ? )

Comment: thank you for your patience Yuval , I learn a lot . thanks ~!

Answer (score 0):

i not recomend the answeor of Yuval Itzchakov beacause you are open and close a lot of socket even open a connection in the broker with kafka is heavy and slow so I Strongly recommend to read this blog https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html i used it and test it and is the best option also I've put in productive environment.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: ifindyourposthardtoreadbecauseoflackofpunctuationandmeaningfullyseparatedsentencespleaseexcusemyexaggerationbyalsodroppingblanks.