# No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a code in which I am trying to consume messages using kafka and spark.
But my code doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{ KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord }
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util._

object Smack_Kafka_Spark extends App {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val kafkaBrokers = "localhost:2181"

val kafkaOpTopic = "test"
/*val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokers)
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")*/

val props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:2181")

props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

var spark: SparkSession = null
val textFile: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile("dataset.txt")
textFile.foreach(record => {
  val data = record.toString
  val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](kafkaOpTopic, null, data)
  producer.send(message)
})
 producer.close()
 }
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Smack_Kafka_Spark$.main(Smack_Kafka_Spark.scala:25)
at Smack_Kafka_Spark.main(Smack_Kafka_Spark.scala)
```

I will be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because `SparkSession` is null. Create it like below.

```
val spark : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Smack_Kafka_Spark")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Now read your text file like below.

```
val textFile: Dataset[String] = spark.read.textFile("dataset.txt")
```

Another issue you might face when you run your program is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
```

The `KafkaProducer` is not serailizable. You would need to move your KafkaProducer instance creation inside foreachPartition. Please check SO post [spark kafka producer serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501046/spark-kafka-producer-serializable)

Comment: Thank you! As you said, the issue of serialization came up. And then I followed the link you had mentioned.

Comment: This is the code corrected: This is the code corrected 


    val textFile: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile("Dataset.txt")
    textFile.foreachPartition((partisions: Iterator[String]) => {
      val producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
      partisions.foreach((line: String) => {
        try {
          producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test", line))
        } catch {
          case ex: Exception => {

          }
        }
      })})

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can add a consumer in this code to retrieve what has been sent by the producer?

Comment: Your Kafka consumer should be different Spark Application. You would need to create StreamingContext and use methods from KafkaUtils classe. Please check sample at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala. You can google and find some working examples as well.